# Entity Framework - стоит ли переходить

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

Долгое время работаю с подключенным уровнем ADO.NET. Все отлично работает, а главное быстро. Но привлекает возможность быстро накидать базу в модели и не думать о ней больше. Кто сталкивался с выбором между двумя этими технологиями - что для себя выбрали и почему ? Спасибо.

Comment: Раз уж вопрос попал в очередь на закрытие - это сравнение старой и новой технологий, с разницей в 10 лет, так что на него есть объективный ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично мое мнение что в любом случае нужно стараться по максимуму использовать или хотя бы знать и примерно понимать как использовать новые технологии, выбор естественно какую точно использовать стоит смотреть на сложность и потребности проекта, я сейчас постоянно использую Entity Framework, потому что он намного более удобен в использовании, не нужно писать SQL, и кучу еще всего что приходится писать в ADO.NET. Код остается чистым и шарповским,не каких намеков на SQL, с LINQ работаешь с базой, просто как с обычной коллекцией и не паришься. Так что как по мне стоит хотя бы попробовать почитать,посмотреть, уведите Вам понравиться.